# Unity Input.touches - action on press and hold delay

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I want tiles(objects on my map) to only change color on a single touch, and not change when I pan or zoom the camera. I have been trying for two days and googled myself out and can't seem to figure it out. It seems pretty simple.

I have been given code to fix this but now I need to add in a time delay as the original code is too sensitive to touch. I was thinking of a "if(touch time > 200ms){don't do anything}else{do stuff} or something like that.

Here is what I have atm:

```
bool onlyTouched;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            onlyTouched = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            onlyTouched = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            if (onlyTouched)
            {
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
                {
                    GameObject ourHitObject = hitInfo.collider.transform.parent.gameObject;

                    if (ourHitObject.GetComponent<Hex>() != null)
                    {
                        Touch_Hex(ourHitObject);
                    }
                    else if (ourHitObject.GetComponent<Unit>() != null)
                    {
                        Touch_Unit(ourHitObject);
                    }
                }
            }
            onlyTouched = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by it's too sensitive? I thought you wanted a single click/touch to change the color...

Comment: Yeah I do,  and that code works but on touch phones etc it often doesn't change colors on touch as it senses microscopic movement in your finger when you touch a tile. You have to be really delicate in your touches and thats not going to be possible with kids etc

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with a bit of tinkering.. I created two floats start/endtime and placed the time of began and ended into these respectively than just used these in an if statement to check if the time between them was less than 0.150.

```
float startTime;
float endTime;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        RaycastHit hitInfo;

        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            startTime = Time.time;
        }
        //Debug.Log("Start time is: " + startTime);
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            endTime = Time.time;
            //Debug.Log("End time is: " + endTime);
            if (endTime - startTime < 0.150f)
            {
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
                {
                    GameObject ourHitObject = hitInfo.collider.transform.parent.gameObject;

                    if (ourHitObject.GetComponent<Hex>() != null)
                    {
                        Touch_Hex(ourHitObject);
                    }
                    else if (ourHitObject.GetComponent<Unit>() != null)
                    {
                        Touch_Unit(ourHitObject);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in getting me on the right track
Cheers